# Implementation of .run() methods in google Cirq

Tags: programming, quantum-algorithms, cirq

I am developing a sampling algorithm using Fourier analysis of Boolean functions for which I use Google's Cirq to obtain the state vector with .simulate().

I wanted to know what sampling algorithm Google Cirq implements with .sample() so that I can have a better idea of how to benchmark it against my algorithm. I have been looking at the docs and source code of cirq.sim.Simulator (https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/sim/Simulator), but I cannot find what sampling algorithm their .run() and .sample() methods use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cirq.Simulator()` uses a statevector simulation algorithm. The resulting statevector is sampled from by first squaring the amplitudes to obtain a probability vector followed by a call to  [numpy.random.Generator.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) ([Here's where it happens](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/d967317cdb0f954e14907f69aaae70fd1f76ff6f/cirq-core/cirq/sim/state_vector.py#L219)) on the probability vector to generate the results.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes total sense now that I see what cirq.value is and .parse_random_state()

The only thing they do is to give the probability distribution and with choice() numpy takes care of giving the resultant values. Thanks again! I was wondering because I am using fourier coefficients to see how I can add noise to the probability distribution and how the XEB is affected by this, so I thought it would make sense to compare it with their .sample() method, but now that I see that they are using the ideal distribution I do not really need to do that.

Comment: You're welcome! Please "Upvote" and "Accept" my answer so that people who find this question in the future can readily know that it answers your question.

Comment: apologies! just did it.